# 'Model' object has no attribute 'load_model' keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to load a model that it was saved with: `model.save('myModel.h5')`

The model is defined like this:

```
self.model = VGGFace(input_tensor=input_tensor, include_top=True)

for layer in self.model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

self.model.get_layer('fc7').trainable = True
last_layer = self.model.get_layer('fc7').output
out = BatchNormalization()(last_layer)
out = Dense(self.n_outputs, activation='softmax', name='fc8')(out)
self.model = Model(input=self.model.input, output=out)
```

when i try to load `myModel.h5` with `model.load_model('myModel.h5')` it throws me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'load_model'
```

I supose it's because i'm not working with `Sequential` models.

How can i load my model then? since `model.save('myModel.h5')` seems to work.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`load_model()` isn't an attribute of an model obejct indeed. `load_model()` is a function imported from keras.models that takes a file name and returns a model obejct.

You should use it like this :

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model(path_to_model)
```

> You can then use keras.models.load_model(filepath) to reinstantiate your model. load_model will also take care of compiling the model using the saved training configuration (unless the model was never compiled in the first place). [from source](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/)

Comment: i can acces to `model.history` loading the entire model right?

Answer (score 4):

The reason is sequential doesn't have a way to load the full model along with optimizer etc only weights. To load the complete model after you performed `model.save('myModel.h5')` you should load the model with

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
#...
myModel = tf.keras.models.load_model("myModel.h5")
```

Comment: This still throws an error when trying to access the history of a model loaded that way:

model.history.history

-> AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'history'